# Git in terminal

Tags: git, github, terminal

I tried making my first repo on github. I copy pasted their code while on the directory of my entire system (I think that was a mistake). As a result, the terminal line always says `~ git:(master) ✗` before every command. It does not go away even when I quit terminal. I am using zsh. The code I pasted was:

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/***/***.git
git push -u origin master
```

On top of that, I can't even seem to figure out how to add my files to the repo. Help on how to not always have git:(master) before every bash command and how to make a repo? Thanks!

Comment: Just curious: Was this done in location `/`? Were you using `sudo` or `root` privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you executed `git init` in `/` directory? If so, maybe just delete  it (`rm -rf /.git`)?

If you want to create a repo just a create a directory and execute `git init` inside that directory.

Comment: Is it possible to run all these `git init` in / without using `sudo`? OP hasn't mentioned he was in sudo mode or root user.

Comment: _the directory of my entire system_
What could he mean by that?

Comment: I have no idea what that means, and that is why I am asking. It could mean the `~` location as well, or whatever location the OP wants it to mean. *You don't need sudo within ~, but with / you do need it*. He most probably has some plugins installed for zsh which tell whether a given directory is a git repo or not. He mentions the `~ git:(master)` which means there is a good chance of him being in `~` directory as well. In which case, suggesting `rm -rf` on any folder within `/` can be a recipe for disaster for a new user.

Comment: It was on /~. I used rm -r /.git, and it seemed to work. Hopefully I didn't screw up my git too badly.

Answer (score 3):

You can un-`init` a git repository by simply erasing it.  It's all in the `.git` directory of when you typed the `git init` command.

You can add files to the repo by using `git add`, but you'd better sort out the “my whole system is under git” issue first.

Comment: @AD7six I'll let the github support pages take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

deleting .git in usr/*username* did the trick for me. I was using Oh My ZSH